# Recursion Depth Cut Off Strategy: Parallel QuickSort

Tags: c++, algorithm, parallel-processing, openmp, quicksort

I have a parallel quickosort alogirthm implemented. To avoid overhead of excess parallel threads I had a cut off strategy to turn the parallel algorithm into a sequential one when the vector size was smaller than a paticular threshold. However, now I am trying to set the cut off strategy based on recursion depth. i.e I want my algorithm to turn sequential when a certain recursion depth is reached. I employed the following code, but it dosent work. I'm not sure how to proceed. Any ideas?

```
template <class T>
void ParallelSort::sortHelper(typename vector<T>::iterator start, typename vector<T>::iterator end, int level =0) //THIS IS THE QUICKSoRT INTERFACE
{
  static int depth =0;

  const int insertThreshold = 20;
  const int threshold = 1000;
  if(start<end)
  {
    if(end-start < insertThreshold) //thresholf for insert sort
    {
      insertSort<T>(start, end);
    }
    else if((end-start) >= insertThreshold && depth<threshold) //threshhold for non parallel quicksort
    {
      int part = partition<T>(start,end);
      depth++;
      sortHelper<T>(start, start + (part - 1), level+1);
      depth--;
      depth++;
      sortHelper<T>(start + (part + 1), end, level+1);
      depth--;
    }
    else
    {
      int part = partition<T>(start,end);
      #pragma omp task
      {
        depth++;
        sortHelper<T>(start, start + (part - 1), level+1);
        depth--;
      }
      depth++;
      sortHelper<T>(start + (part + 1), end, level+1);
      depth--;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried the static variable `depth` and also the non static variable `level` but both of them dont work.
NOTE: The above snipped only depends on `depth`. `level` is included to show both the methods  tried

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? How different is it from the expected behaviour?

Comment: I meant that it wasnt giving me a speedup. But I've figured it out (answer below). Thanks for looking in anyway.

Comment: Assume single threaded operation.  Then in what call to `sortHelper<T>` is `depth` not equal to `level`?  The number of recursive calls is `level`.  Get rid of `static depth`, static variables you write to have little place in parallel code.

Comment: And a recursion binary tree of depth 20 has 1 million entries.  In your case, you'll instead have an undefined depth (because the value of `static depth` is undefined in your code, as multiple threads are writing to it without any lock guards).

Comment: Who knows how much you lose on cold-cache effects by starting a herd of threads, and how much useless cache bouncing you get when two cores start fighting over the cache line containing the part of the array they are frobbing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`static depth` being written to from two threads makes your code execute unspecified behavior, as what those writes do is not specified.

As it happens, you are passing down `level`, which is your recursion depth.  At each level, you double the number of threads -- so a limit on level equal to 6 (say) corresponds to 2^6 threads at most.  Your code is only half parallel, because the `partition` code occurs in the main thread, so you will probably have fewer than the theoretical maximum number of threads going at once.

```
template <class T>
void ParallelSort::sortHelper(typename vector<T>::iterator start, typename vector<T>::iterator end, int level =0) //THIS IS THE QUICKSoRT INTERFACE
{

  const int insertThreshold = 20;
  const int treeDepth = 6; // at most 2^6 = 64 tasks
  if(start<end)
  {
    if(end-start < insertThreshold) //thresholf for insert sort
    {
      insertSort<T>(start, end);
    }
    else if(level>=treeDepth) // only 2^treeDepth threads, after which we run in sequence
    {
      int part = partition<T>(start,end);
      sortHelper<T>(start, start + (part - 1), level+1);
      sortHelper<T>(start + (part + 1), end, level+1);
    }
    else // launch two tasks, creating an exponential number of threads:
    {
      int part = partition<T>(start,end);
      #pragma omp task
      {
        sortHelper<T>(start, start + (part - 1), level+1);
      }
      sortHelper<T>(start + (part + 1), end, level+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out. It was a stupid mistake on my part.

The algorithm should fall back onto the sequential code when the stack size is greater than some threshold, **not smaller**. Doing so solves the problem, and gives me a speedup.

Comment: Nah, it doesn’t work. What you’re observing is a glitch. You cannot use a static variable (`depth`) across threads in the fashion in which you try to use it. The behaviour that you get is completely spurious.

Comment: You're right. The static `depth` isn't fail safe. Using `level` with the above answer works though